# Symfony ACL assign ROLE to user and check if granted

Tags: symfony, permissions, acl, roles

In Symfony docs we can read on how we can check if user has specific ROLe, and this can be easily done with:

```
if ($this->decisionManager->decide($token, array('ROLE_ADMIN'))) {
        return true;
    }
```

But documents are not describing how we can grant ROLE_ADMIN to specific user so that above code will work, because most of the examples in docs are showing that ROLE is granted on some specific object/class:

```
 $aclProvider = $this->getContainer()->get('security.acl.provider');

// Use class for object identity as below
$oid = new ObjectIdentity('acme_post', 'Your\\AcmeBundle\\Entity\\Post');

$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($oid);

$securityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity("ROLE_ADMIN");
// grant owner access to users with above role
$acl->insertClassAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
```

In this example the first snippet wont work unless we use

```
$this->decisionManager->decide($token, array('ROLE_ADMIN'),$entityPost)
```

I don't need to know if he has permission/role for specific object/class, but if he has role in general, like

```
$user->getRoles();
```

Which returns all roles that user has, but isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') doesn't work, even if above code returns array with ROLE_ADMIN inside.

Comment: how $this->decisionManager->decide() works : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html   and also :   http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles

Comment: Even if I use 
$app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') 

it does not validate it, even tho $app['security.authorization_checker'] contains ROLE_ADMIN in roles(). 

I know about the decision manager and voters, but even authorization_checker does not seem to work OK or at least not as it is described in docs.